# Is there a single REST endpoint to fetch (Microsoft) Onedrive File tree?

Tags: rest, cloud, onedrive

I want a recursive list of files and folders from say, root of the drive. One way would be to fetch the folder contents and then issue listing for each of the sub folders recursively. As this would take a lot of time, is there a single REST endpoint for 'Onedrive' which would fetch the entire folder structure from the root or from a designated folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such API at this time.